# PHP Mail (cakephp 3.4.x) error Peer certificate CN=\`cpanel44.proisp.no' did not match expected

Tags: email, ssl, smtp, cakephp-3.0, cpanel

I'm trying to send email from my cakephp app. The app url is subdomain.domain.com. We have set up domain.com to work with microsoft office 365.

Emails are being sent when I do it from my virtual box (cakebox), but when I try on the production server (hosted shared server by proisp.no), I can't. The hosted server is running linux with cPanel.

What is strange, is that just a few days ago, if not even until I made some changes today, I could send emails. The changes I did was adding a plugin, EmailQueue, and adding a new table for queue, and of course some simple coding. I will remind you, it works from my virtual box, but still not on the production server.

Also, neither sending mail with Cake\Mailer\Email works on prod. server now.

The error I get is:

> SMTP server did not accept the connection or trying to connect to non TLS SMTP server using TLS.
>   Email 1 was not sent
>   Warning Error: stream_socket_enable_crypto(): Peer certificate CN=`cpanel44.proisp.no' did not match expected CN=`smtp.office365.com' in [/home/username/tools/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Network/Socket.php, line 433]
>
> 2017-05-09 22:41:42 Warning: Warning (2): stream_socket_enable_crypto(): Peer certificate CN=`cpanel44.proisp.no' did not match expected CN=`smtp.office365.com' in [/home/username/tools/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Network/Socket.php, line 433]
>   Trace:
>   Cake\Error\BaseErrorHandler::handleError() - CORE/src/Error/BaseErrorHandler.php, line 153
>   stream_socket_enable_crypto - [internal], line ??
>   Cake\Network\Socket::enableCrypto() - CORE/src/Network/Socket.php, line 433
>   Cake\Mailer\Transport\SmtpTransport::_connect() - CORE/src/Mailer/Transport/SmtpTransport.php, line 226
>   Cake\Mailer\Transport\SmtpTransport::send() - CORE/src/Mailer/Transport/SmtpTransport.php, line 162
>   Cake\Mailer\Email::send() - CORE/src/Mailer/Email.php, line 2052
>   EmailQueue\Shell\SenderShell::main() - ROOT/vendor/lorenzo/cakephp-email-queue/src/Shell/SenderShell.php, line 100
>   Cake\Console\Shell::runCommand() - CORE/src/Console/Shell.php, line 472
>   Cake\Console\ShellDispatcher::_dispatch() - CORE/src/Console/ShellDispatcher.php, line 230
>   Cake\Console\ShellDispatcher::dispatch() - CORE/src/Console/ShellDispatcher.php, line 182
>   Cake\Console\ShellDispatcher::run() - CORE/src/Console/ShellDispatcher.php, line 128
>   [main] - ROOT/bin/cake.php, line 34

This is my setup:

```
'EmailTransport' => [
    'default' => [
        'className' => 'Smtp',
        // The following keys are used in SMTP transports
        'host' => 'smtp.office365.com',
        'port' => 587,
        'timeout' => 30,
        'username' => 'name@domain.com',
        'password' => 'password',
        'client' => null,
        'tls' => true,
        'url' => env('EMAIL_TRANSPORT_DEFAULT_URL', null),
    ],
    'Debug' => [
        'className' => 'Debug',
        // The following keys are used in SMTP transports
        'host' => 'smtp.office365.com',
        'port' => 587,
        'timeout' => 30,
        'username' => 'name@domain.com',
        'password' => 'password',
        'client' => null,
        'tls' => null,
        'url' => env('EMAIL_TRANSPORT_DEFAULT_URL', null),
    ],
],

'Email' => [
    'default' => [
        'transport' => 'default',
        'from' => 'name@domain.com',
    ],
    'debug' => [
        'transport' => 'Debug',
        'from' => 'name@domain.com',
    ],
],
```

Comment: The bit about `Peer certificate CN=`cpanel44.proisp.no' did not match expected CN=`smtp.office365.com'` would seem to indicate that it's trying to connect to your server to send, rather than Office365. Is your transport configuration available when running from the CLI?

Comment: I'm running through bin/cake EmailQueue.sender. Locally it works, on shared host it doesn't (through SSH). Not sure how to tell if it is avaiable. I tried a new email I set up with cPanel which worked when sending through SMTP without SSL (mail.mydomain.no). With SSL it timed out. I have contacted my host to see if anythings blocking the connection, but I doubt that is the case.

Comment: I dont know how this issue turned up at all, but after clearing the cache it worked as normal.